# [WARNING:Refusing to load for invalid virtual URL: %22https://m.movie.sg/sm_seatselect.aspx?filmID=

Tags: android, url, android-intent

Currently I have some urls that need to either intent Action.view and display in browser or using a webview,
but my url will always cause errors,
the original link is with space, then I replace space with %20, but uri.parse will always look at the url with spacing, I dont know why.

> "https://m.movie.sg/sm_seatselect.aspx?filmID=191%2016%20252%2019%20222%20253%2086%20155%20225%20137%20103%207%2071%2031%20189%20100&cinemaID=38%20139%20232%20165%20234%20202%20185%20190%20171%20225%20253%20138%2045%2029%2098%20224&scheduleID=3%2049%20217%2041%20184%2094%20161%2087%20228%20106%2027%20167%20106%20144%20186%20196&promoID=&skipSeatSelect=n%20&numSeats=0"

May I know why such url cant be use ?
thank you

Comment: what is your actual url?

Comment: thanks for the reply, it found out that the link I get with " " inside the string causes the webview didnt work properly.

Comment: So it is working now?

Comment: yes, thank you so much for taking your time to reply me:)